# Is it possible to force Re-creation of EC2::Instance or RDS::DBInstance in amazon cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudformation

It's possible to force the re-creation of a EC2 or RDS instance using cloudformation stacks?

My stack goes stuck in a point where simply destroying and creating the resource will fix it, instead of that I had to delete entire stack to continue work.

edit:

This issue hit me twice. First I created an AWS::RDS::Instance with some defaults and then tried to downgrade it to "EngineVersion" : "5.5". Changing this its suposed to happen with some interruption, but mysql instances cannot be downgraded from 5.6 to 5.5 so the stack was left in UPDATE_FAILED state and I cannot be able to recreate RDS without a nasty trick.

The other occurrence was that i have several "AWS::EC2::Instance" which downloads and executes an script from it's "UserData" obviously if Y change the downloaded script I must recrete the instance, and theres no way to do so. Once again I use the same nasty trick to get the machine recreated.

The nasty trick:

Instead of using an autoscaling group of one machine, I solved both problems changing the availability zone in the properties... but left me with a bad taste

Comment: Need more info to answer. Do your instances freeze on startup?  Does a service become unresponsive?  If you're looking to manually recreate an EC2 instance, you can create an auto-scaling group with one instance.  When you terminate the instance, another will be created.

Comment: edited for clarify. I also asked here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=135295&tstart=0

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but for re-running UserData scripts when changed, you could look into `cfn-hup`: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-hup.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For instance store-backed EC2 instances, one trick is to add a comment to the user data script containing a version number, date, or similar, then change that whenever you want the instance recreated:

```
{
    "Resources" : {
        "MyEC2Instance" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties" : {
                // ... other properties ...
                "UserData": { 
                    "Fn::Base64" : {
                        "Fn::Join" : [ ":", [
                        "#!/bin/bash\n",
                        "# Version: 1.0\n",
                        // ... rest of user data ...
                    ]]}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any change to `UserData` will cause the instance to be replaced (i.e., regenerated). The behavior of the user data script should be the same, though, since the only modification is a comment. Note that this doesn't work for EBS-backed instances.

For RDS, you could take a [DB snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html) of the current RDS instance, then modify your template to use that snapshot with `DBSnapshotIdentifier`:

```
{
    "Resources" : {
        "MyDB" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
        "Properties" : {
            // ... other properties ...
            "DBSnapshotIdentifier": "<db snapshot ID>"
        }
    }    
}
```

Whenever `DBSnapshotIdentifier` is changed, the database instance will be replaced. Using snapshots will also let you keep the data from when the snapshot was made. (If you *want* to wipe the data, you could create an empty snapshot and pass that as input. Or delete and recreate the entire CloudFormation stack.)

A more generic approach is to change the logical name of the resource. From  [Modifying a Stack Template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-get-template.html) in the CloudFormation docs:

> For most resources, changing the logical name of a resource is equivalent to deleting that resource and replacing it with a new one. Any other resources that depend on the renamed resource also need to be updated and might cause them to be replaced. Other resources require you to update a property (not just the logical name) in order to trigger an update.

Comment: Seems that the only solution is to do "dirty tricks" I reached a similar solution (forcing availability zones changes) some time after asking :)

Comment: Just want to point out that the instance is replaced and thus the UserData executed when the EC2 instance is instance store -backed. If it is EBS backed, the change of UserData will only make the instance restart and UserData is not executed again. You can use cfn-hup to get the UserData run again even in this case, but the instance stays the same.

Comment: @Kaitsu: Thanks, that's a very valuable clarification. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Kaitsu but if you manually re-run the script (located at /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001) you have to make sure the script is defensive to running the same commands multiple times :(

Answer (score 1):

If you put it into an AutoScalingGroup, you can edit the AutoScalingGroup min/max/default to 0, then as soon as it starts to destroy the old instance, you can then put the min/max/default to 1/1/1 and presto:  new instance.

Answer (score 0):

If your EC2 are into an AutoScalingGroup you can set the `AutoScalingGroupName` property with a version number in it.

Every time you change that version number CFN will:
1. create a new auto-scaling group and spin up the desired instances
2. kill instances in the old auto-scaling group and delete it

Here is a piece of code from my stack where I use this technique to force a large number of EC2 machines to re-create and automatically pull new software from S3.

```
AutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
        AutoScalingGroupName: !Sub "${StackName}-${ServiceName}-${ServiceVersion}"
```